# B+ Tree structure implementation using SQL

Tags: sql, database-design, tree, relational-database

I'm well aware of the existing binary search tree implementations in pure sql, but I can't really imagine how one would construct a database model implementing the B+ Tree data structure. Is it even possible ?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you be more specific what you want to know?

Comment: B-Trees are used to implement indexes which, in turn, improve the performance of the relational databases. So you see, you could theoretically implement a relational database without any B-Trees, but the performance would suck. By the way, "B" in B-Tree doesn't stand for "binary". It is indeed not unusual to have a B-Tree node that is hundreds of keys wide.

Answer (score 0):

1. B+Tree and Binary search are not the same.
2. It is possible to use B+Tree structure (assuming you know what it is) in tables.

If 2 is recommended or not is something worth research but our company does it a lot.

An example of using B+Tree on a table would be:

```
ColId       SomeData        ParentId
------------------------------------
  1           Data 1          null
  2           Data 2          null
  3           Data 3            1
  4           Data 4            1
  5           Data 5            3
```

And so on. The idea being that you can find the parent of item 5, by looking at the parent id. And there are all sorts of handy algorithms you can make / reuse to find items and their places. Using ColId's with larger increments i.e. increments of 10 or 100 for example lets you leave space for inserting items into the tree.

For example...The parent of Item 5 is Item 3. And the grandparent is Item 1. Anything with null are root (starting) items...They have no parent.

As you can imagine this is quite fast to search through, but quite slow to update or add (if you don't leave space as recommended above). If you do leave space, then it's only slow to add when you run out of space and have to rewrite the items. Assuming you taught your data out well, this should not happen often. If it does, then perhaps B+Tree is not really ideal for that particular format. In general, B+Tree structures are great if the majority of operations on your data is reading / searching / filtering etc. But if there is a lot of updates and additions, perhaps not so good.

As your question seemed to be about how to use B+Tree format in sql server tables, I will leave you to look at the difference between this and a binary search. Binary search is an algorithm used to search for something by first sorting the set, then dividing by half each time until you find what you are looking for. B+Tree can also be used for searching, but is different because it operates on a hierarchical structure (hence the name Tree).

Comment: I figured that much out. I was hoping I could learn how to structure a query to find a tree.